# Remove of data folder is not synced in Elasticsearch upon index delete

Tags: elasticsearch

We have an ES cluster with 2 nodes. When we delete an index not all folders in the cluster (on filesystem) are deleted which causes some problems when restarting one server.

Then our deleted indices gets distributed with some weird state indicating that the cluster health is not green.

Example. We delete index with name someIndex and after deletion we check file system, one can see this:

Node1
ElasticSearch\data\clustername\nodes\0\indices\
ElasticSearch\data\clustername\nodes\1\indices\

Node2
ElasticSearch\data\clustername\nodes\0\indices\ 
ElasticSearch\data\clustername\nodes\1\indices\someIndex (<-- still present)

Anyone know whats causing this?

ES-version: 0.90.5

Answer (score 2):

There are two nodes directories for each on your filesystem (these are nodes\0 and nodes\1).

When you start Elasticsearch, you start up a node (in ES-lingo). Your machine can host multiple nodes, which happens if you start Elasticsearch multiple times. The [default settings](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html#modules-http) for the http port is `9200-9300`, that means, ES is looking for a free port in that range and binds its node to it (the same is true for the [transport module](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-transport.html#modules-transport) with `9300-9400`)

So, if you start an ES process while another is still running, that is, it's bound to a port, you start a second node and ES will create a new directory for it. Maybe this has happened if you issued a restart, but ES couldn't shut down in time before the new node started up.

But now you have a third node in your cluster and ES will assign shards to it. Then you do a cluster restart or something similar and you start one node on each of your machine. ES cannot find the shards that were assigned to the third node, because it's not spun up, and it will show you a red or yellow state, depending on what shards live on the third node. If you delete you index data, you won't delete the data from this missing node.

If you don't care about the data, you can just shutdown ES and delete these directories or start two ES nodes on each of your machines and then delete the index again.

Then you could change the port settings to one specific port, that would prevent second processes from starting up, since they won't be able to bind to a free port.

Comment: Hmm, that might be the case. So if I only run one node per server there shouldn't be more than one folder in clustername\nodes\ on each server then? Is there any setting that prohibits more than one node.

Comment: @Marcus open `config/elasticsearch.yml` and uncomment the `node.max_local_storage_nodes: 1` line. That way you can only start a single node from that installation path.